# Using MutationObserver to observe attribute change for a specific attribute only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, mutation-observers

I have a list of items and I am using Mutation Observer to check whether items are added or removed from that list. The code looks like this:

```
 function TrackListChange(elementId) {
                const targetNode = document.getElementById(elementId);
                const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
                const callback = function (mutationsList, observer) {

                    for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
                        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
                            alert("added to list"); 
                        }
                        if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
                            alert("removed from list"); 
                        }
                    }
                };
                const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
                observer.observe(targetNode, config);

            }
```

The issue I am having is that when I remove an item from the list, TWO class attributes change, and it tracks both of them. I only want the alert to be called once, when an item is removed  from the list. To try to explain better, here is the code:

```
<div class="divclass active">
 <ul class="items-list" id="user-items">
  <li id="newitem1"></li> 
  <li id="newitem2"></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

When I add an item, a new

item is added, simple as that, no other changes. This works fine. However, when I remove an item and try to inspect what is happening, the

element is changing but so is the  element. Due to the way the project has been coded, the

element adds a class to the removed item that says 'class="hidden"'.

I apologise as I know that it is quite difficult without seeing the changes in the console, and it's also difficult for me to debug. Essentially, is there a way I can check on a specific attribute that is changing? E.g. when the item is removed and the 'hidden' class is added to the element, can I check for that particular attribute change instead of all of them?

Hopefully this is explained enough for someone to point me in the right direction?

Comment: The only filtering feature is [attributeFilter](https://devdocs.io/dom/mutationobserverinit/attributefilter) which accepts a list of attribute names. There's no way to specify a filter by attribute value so it's something your code should do explicitly in the callback.

Comment: It's not exactly what you're afted, but would [debouncing](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-use-the-debounce-function-in-javascript) your function help? A debounced function only fires once every X seconds, so even if the MutationObserver triggers multiple times, you'd still only get one function call.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `attributes` option to `false` in the second parameter to `.observe()`, it won't notify you of changes to attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this attributes default value will be false so adding property attributeFilter will work for you:

```
const pageObserver = new MutationObserver(callback);
  pageObserver.observe(targetNode, {
    subtree: true,
    childList: true,
    attributeFilter: ['aria-selected'],
  });
```